# How to require running serviced service in RPM

Tags: rpm, systemd

We have an RPM package that requires a running Docker service to perform its installation. (Part of the RPM package is going to install new Docker images on the system).

Is there a standard way (like package dependencies) in the RPM spec to require that a specific systemd service is running?

Answer (score 0):

In your `%pre` section, you can call `systemctl` - there are some examples on https://rpm-packaging-guide.github.io